# Replacing selected parts of an item in Python list

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list looking as follows

```
lst = ['.ab.cd.ef.gh.', '.ij.kl.mn.op.']
```

In each item, I want to replace `item[0]` with a `*` and `item[-1]` with a `$`.

I tried to use:

```
[item.eplace(item[0], '*') for item in lst]
```

but the result is that all `.` get replaced with `*`  irrespective of position.

Appreciating your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work:

```
>>> lst = ['.ab.cd.ef.gh.', '.ij.kl.mn.op.']
>>> ['*' + item[1:-1] + '$' for item in lst]
['*ab.cd.ef.gh$', '*ij.kl.mn.op$']
>>>
```

`item[1:-1]`, which uses [Explain Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/pythons-slice-notation#509295), will get every character in `item` except for the first and the last:

```
>>> 'abcde'[1:-1]
'bcd'
>>> '*' + 'abcde'[1:-1] + '$'  # Add the characters we want on each end
'*bcd$'
>>>
```

Comment: thank you for your help. Still I have one more question. How can I loop over characters of items in a list and perform operations on them. For example
for item in lst:
       for char in lst[item]:
                if char == so and so:
                         do this action

Comment: Please pardon me because I cannot format the code. I am just typing from my mobile device.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
lst = ['.ab.cd.ef.gh.', '.ij.kl.mn.op.']
for k in range(0, len(lst)):
    item = lst[k]
    lst[k] = '*'+item[1:-1]+'$'

print lst
```

This loops over every item with a `for` loop and `range()`, and assigns `lst[k]` to `item`. Then it uses `item[1:-1]` to get the string excluding the first and last characters. Then we use string concatenation to add an asterisk to the beginning, and a dollar sign to the end. This runs as:

```
>>> lst = ['.ab.cd.ef.gh.', '.ij.kl.mn.op.']
>>> for k in range(0, len(lst)):
...     item = lst[k]
...     lst[k] = '*'+item[1:-1]+'$'
... 
>>> print lst
['*ab.cd.ef.gh$', '*ij.kl.mn.op$']
>>>
```